# Azure AD B2C - User flows (policies)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I had a page that shows the list of registered users. In the list, each row had delete and edit functionalities. Take the list page into action as an administrator view. He/she need to edit each registered users basic information. For collecting the information I call APIs. In an administrative role how can I update all the users information? Which User flows (policies) I need to try ?

Comment: Is the list user experience hosted in your app/website? Or  this question is about Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes, user experience hosted in your app/website.

Answer (score 0):

The User Policies are intended to be used by the Consumers (users). Admins can delete or edit users in the Users blade in the Azure Portal.

If that's not acceptable in your case, you could easy create your own admin page to update the user attributes via Graph API calls.

Answer (score 0):

User flows are used for the end user. Where end user can go through a user journey to accomplish something such as signup, signin, password reset etc.

For Admin experiences for user modification, there are two ways

1. Use Azure portal as it provides a rich experience already. You can use RBAC to provide limited access to the user management admins.
2. Use AAD Graph apis to build your own custom user management flows. You can find documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)